# How can I remove tags which have at least one attribute except except specific attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea which my website's users enter their own content in it *(based on **markdown** standards)* and then publish it in my website.

The library I use *(which converts markdown to HTML per `keydown`)* produces tags without attributes.  So to keep safe the UI against what the user enters, I have this code:

```
function cleanHtml(html) {
    var $doc = $('<span>' + html + '</span>');
    $('*', $doc).each(function (index, el) {
        if (el.hasAttributes('attributes')) {
            while ($(el).contents().length) {
                $(el).contents().last().insertAfter(el);
            }
            $(el).remove();
        }
    });
    return $doc.html();
}
```

The Code above removes every tag which has at least one attribute. This works fine.

Recently I figured out the markdown-converter-library also produces some tags which have either the *href* attribute or both `src` and `alt` attributes. Something like these:

```
<a href="../path">my link</a>
<img src="../path" alt="something" />
```

Now I need to edit `cleanHtml()` function to remove every tag which has attributes except the two examples above.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is `hasAttributes()` definition? AFAIK, jQuery has `hasAttr()`

Comment: @AdamAzad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttributes

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$(el).attr('src')` or `$(el).attr('src')` return undefined:

```
el.hasAttributes('attributes') && ( !$(el).attr('src') && !$(el).attr('href') )
```

```js
$('*').each(function(i, el){
    if(el.hasAttributes('attributes') && ( !$(el).attr('src') && !$(el).attr('href') )  ) {
      $(el).remove();
   } 
});
```

```css
p {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://unsplash.it" style="color:#f44336">my link</a>
<a href="http://unsplash.it" style="color:#f44336;size:16px">Unsplash 2</a>
<img src="http://unsplash.it/100" alt="something" />
<p id="s" data-a="a"></p>
```

Comment: In your case, this will not be removed *(which should be)*: `<a hred="../path" style="color:red;">mylink</a>`

Comment: @stack, you were right, I attached a snippet code with it. Bear in mind, the user input can be modified to inject `onload` with a XSS code to the img tag.

Comment: upvote, I see, thank you for the tip. And how can I make my UI safe against XSS attacks?

Comment: Remove those attributes using from the nodes in the loop, should be simple. I would recommend checking for those attributes in server-side as user can always tamper the data HTTP requests. If the server-side is Node.js, you can load cheerio (a jQuery-like library to modify DOM string). :) Good luck and happy coding